# Create new column with an array of range of numbers

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

So I need to create an array of numbers enumerating from 1 to 100 as the value for each row as an extra column.

Using the `array()` function with a bunch of literal values works, but surely there's a way to use / convert a Scala `Range(a to b)` instead of listing each number individually?

```
spark.sql("SELECT key FROM schema.table")
  .otherCommands
  .withColumn("range", array(lit(1), lit(2), ..., lit(100)))
```

To something like:

```
withColumn("range", array(1 to 100))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `map` function using `lit` inbuilt function inside `array` function as

```
df.withColumn("range", array((1 to 100).map(lit(_)): _*))
```

Answer (score 10):

From Spark 2.4 you can use [sequence][1] function
If you have this dataframe:

```
df.show()
+--------+
|column_1|
+--------+
|       1|
|       2|
|       3|
|       0|
+--------+
```

If you use the sequence function from 0 to column_1 you got this:

```
df.withColumn("range", sequence(lit(0), col("column_1"))).show()
+--------+------------+
|column_1|       range|
+--------+------------+
|       1|      [0, 1]|
|       2|   [0, 1, 2]|
|       3|[0, 1, 2, 3]|
|       0|         [0]|
+--------+------------+
```

For this case, set both values with `lit`:

```
df.withColumn("range", sequence(lit(0), lit(100)))
```

Answer (score 3):

For **Spark 2.2+** a new function [`typedLit`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#typedLit-T-scala.reflect.api.TypeTags.TypeTag-) was introduced that easily solves this problem without using `.map(lit(_))` on the array. From the documentation:

> The difference between this function and lit is that this function can handle parameterized scala types e.g.: List, Seq and Map.

Use as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.typedLit

df.withColumn("range", typedLit((1 to 100).toList))
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of **PySpark**:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
DF.withColumn("range",F.array([F.lit(i) for i in range(1,11)]))
```

I hope the above answer is useful.

Answer (score -2):

Tested this solution with spark version 2.2.0

Please try this simple way for the same thing:

```
val df = spark.range(5).toDF("id")
df.withColumn("range", lit(1 to 10 toArray)).show(false)
```

The output of the code:

```
+---+-------------------------------+
|id |range                          |
+---+-------------------------------+
|0  |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]|
|1  |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]|
|2  |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]|
|3  |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]|
|4  |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]|
+---+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: This does not work: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class [I [I@427a0746`

Comment: I have tested solution before posting it. and here is the output for the same. val df = spark.range(5).toDF("id")
    df.withColumn("range", lit(1 to 10 toArray)).show(false)

Comment: Added the output for the same @ChiMo

Comment: I am using Spark version 2.0.2.6, perhaps have a comment on what versions would support this.